# get value from key in sessionStorage javascript

Tags: javascript, sessionstorage

Is it possible to check if a specific value exists in a key in sessionStorage?

Let's say that I have a key that is named "item" and I got digits in that key. I want to check if the digit "5" exists in item.

I have tested to write like this:

```
  if(sessionStorage.getItem("item") == "5");
```

but It doesn't respond as i want.

Is there another way I can check if the digit 5 exists in item?

Comment: what's wrong with your code? What do you mean by : "It doesn't respond as i want"?

Comment: I want to decide wich kind of function to call. I know for fact that Item has digit 5 and therefore i want to check the whole item key. 

       if(sessionStorage.getItem("Item") == "5")
         object.addEventListener("click", function, false); 
      else
           anotherobject.addEventListener("click", anotherfunction,false);

Comment: `sessionStorage `returns the value as a string. So you need to split it to get your initial array.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if I understood you correctly, but I assume you have item in your session storage, e.g.:

`sessionStorage.setItem("item", 12345)`

Then, you want to check if there is a number 5 in it. You can do it by typing

`sessionStorage.getItem("item").indexOf(5) > -1`

Comment: Good idea, but it will not be great when I have number 18 in the key and want to search for number 8. Then it thinks it's there.

Comment: "When I have number 18 in the key" - being exact, you mean 18 in the value? If you set:

`sessionStorage.setItem(18, 12345)`

Then the result for that:

`sessionStorage.getItem(18).indexOf(8) > -1`

is of course false.

If you want to check exact value in chosen key, just type:

`sessionStorage.setItem("item", 18)`
`sessionStorage.getItem("item") === 8`   

The last line should return false.

Comment: I mean that I have 18 as value in item, then it shows that 8 is also available. Keep in mind that the item is designed like this. "Item: [" 1 "," 2 "," 18 ",] etc.

Comment: Ok, that changes a lot. If you store your data as array, treat them so. `sessionStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify(["1", "2", "18"]));`

`var numbers = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("items"));`

`numbers.indexOf("18") > -1`

Comment: `sessionStorage.getItem("items")` returns a string, how do you want to parse it as a JSON?

Comment: @edkeveked That's the goal of JSON.parse() function. According to docs:
"The JSON.parse() method parses a JSON string, constructing the JavaScript value or object described by the string." 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: I wonder if you tried what you are suggesting. You will get an error

Comment: What kind of error? Tried in chrome console, works well.

Comment: Now I see, you are using first `JSON.stringify` before storing the items; otherwise it won't work when you will retrieve it with `JSON.parse`

Answer (score 0):

`sessionStorage` is returning the value as a string and not as an object array. So you can first use [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/String/split) to get the array you set in initially.

So whether you do this:

```
sessionStorage.setItem("item", [1,2,3])
```

or this:

```
sessionStorage.setItem("item", ["1","2","3"])
```

`sessionStorage.getItem("item")` will return this: `"1,2,3"` (string)

After splitting your string,

- You can use [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/indexOf),

```js
if(sessionStorage.getItem("item").split(",").indexOf("5") > -1){
  //do your computation
}
```

- You can also use [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/includes)

```js
if(sessionStorage.getItem("item").split(",").includes("5")){
  //do your computation
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
sessionStorage.setItem("item", "53");
if (sessionStorage.getItem("item").indexOf("5") > -1) {
    // sessionStorage item has number "5"
}
```